# How to center unicode symbol as a text inside of Button in layout (android xml)?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, padding, centering

I am creating calculator for Android. In my layout.xml file I have `<LinearLayout>` and a `<Button>` inside. I want to have a button with one-symbol text in it, which must be centered horizontally and vertically. I've succeeded to center most of text symbols, except arrows, which Unicodes are `\u2190` and `\u2192`. Is it possible to fix the problem using paddings or `android:gravity`? Or there's a more complex solution?

In this screenshot you can find an [example of incorrect arrows' positioning along with correct other symbols' positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJO6i.png)

I tried several combinations of `android:textSize`, 'android:paddingBottom' and 'android:paddingTop' with different values. I expect that simple 'android:paddingBottom' with certain parameter should help me but if I specify value more than `10dp`, text starts to shift up, not down.

Here's my `layout.xml`:

```
<Button
   style="@style/ExtraButtonStyle"
   android:text="\u2190"
   android:textSize="44dp"
   android:paddingBottom="4dp"
   android:id="@+id/left_arrow">
</Button>
```

And here's my `styles.xml` file with applied styles:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyButtonStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">60dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">60dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">30dp</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ExtraButtonStyle" parent="MyButtonStyle">
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/grey</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete in `layout.xml` the line

```
android:paddingBottom="4dp"
```

and add in `MainActivity` after the line

```
Button buttonLeftArrow = findViewById(R.id.left_arrow);
```

the additional line

```
buttonLeftArrow.setPadding(0,0,0,32);
```

[image]

**EDIT:**  Sorry, I forgot in my first answer an important change I made to get the pictured button: Your font size 44dp is much too big for a button of size 60x60dp. Then paddingBottom no longer works as expected and creates wired effects because there is simply too little space for this font size and this paddingBottom.

So you only have to change the following two numbers in your `layout.xml`:

```
android:textSize="22dp"
android:paddingBottom="15dp"
```

If you increase the font size, the weird effects start, if you decrease it, everything works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for advice but that didn't actually work out. The arrow did really shift up a little, however, it's not centered yet. I tried to adjust the value `32` but the arrow doesn't shift up anymore even if I set `50`, for example. Moreover, if I set `100` it actually disappears from the button, so the behaviour is very unpredictable.

Comment: The code I entered worked for me, as the screenshot proves. I used Android Studio Hedgehog (2023.1.1), compiled against SDK 34, created a new project and copied your code 1 : 1. And you?

Comment: I use Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 and compile against 34 SDK. Probably, I should share full `layout.xml` file? I really can't see the consecutive logic between the padding I set and how the arrow really moves inside a button.

Comment: even if this worked, it doesn't really explain why or what it's doing, might be a better answer if you explained what `buttonLeftArrow.setPadding(0,0,0,32);` is doing and why it would solve the problem

Comment: @ Fedorucho: Hm, the full layout.xml probably doesn't help much. I suggest that you also create a new project, copy exactly the code you have specified **here** into it, and add the two lines I have listed to MainActivity. If you don't get the same screen as me, you probably have different implementations in gradle.build.

Comment: @Cloverleaf thanks for the edit. It did really solve the problem and now my arrow is centered (I used `android:paddingBottom="15dp"` and `android:textSize="25dp"`! The last question is: is it possible to make the arrow larger and still remain it in the center? Currently it looks a bit small comparing to the other symbols and objects on the screen .

Comment: There are many variations of the arrow in Unicode, see e.g. https://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/arrow. You can get a slightly thicker arrow, for example, using android:paddingTop="0dp", android:paddingBottom="6dp", android:paddingStart="0dp", android:paddingEnd="0dp", android:text="\u279C", android:textSize="30dp". However, also consider a TextView: these also have the setOnClickListener method, but have more freedom in their design than a button.